# C# Linq .Distinct() method not working

Tags: c#, linq

Does C# Linq Distinct has stopped working recently?
Few months ago it was working like a charm now it is not. For example when I try to do this

```
Product[] products = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                   new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 }, 
                   new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                   new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

IEnumerable<Product> noduplicates =
products.Distinct();
foreach (var product in noduplicates)
Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);

This code should produce the following output:
apple 9 
orange 4
lemon 12
```

But it produces the following output:
    apple 9 
    orange 4
    apple 9
    lemon 12

Comment: Can it be that the Product class had a CompareTo method implemented which was removed or changed?

Comment: Linq Distinct is working properly. But you are not using it correctly. Hint: implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in your `Product` class.

Comment: You need to tell LINQ how you define equality between products by providing an `IEqualityComparer<Product>` or making `Product` implement `IEquatable<Product>`.

Comment: I stand corrected @IvanStoev mentioned the proper methods although the issue is pretty much the same.